# In Apache Airflow, why is the execution date not the same as the trigger time?

Tags: airflow

I'm just learning Apache Airflow. I understand that the execution date is not the same time as the actual time a dag run is triggered.

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.

> Let’s Repeat That The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

I humbly ask: Does anybody know the reason for this decision? It seems rather confusing calling the start date by that name, what exactly starts at the start date? What is executed at execution date?

Comment: I think you are mixing things up a little bit: The start time and the trigger time are indeed different things, but the execution time is yet another different thing, which shows when your task was able to actually get executed once it was triggered. I think your question is about the former two and not the latter, and you might want to edit your title to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

From the same [docs](http://apache-airflow-docs.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs/apache-airflow/latest/concepts/scheduler.html):

> For dags with a cron or timedelta schedule, scheduler won’t trigger
> your tasks until the period it covers has ended e.g., A job with
> schedule set as @daily runs after the day has ended. **This technique
> makes sure that whatever data is required for that period is fully
> available before the DAG is executed.**

Answer (score 1):

you can think of the start date as the date you give the schedule to let it know when it should start applying the aforementioned logic in order for your dags to be scheduled.

To borrow a doc snippet of the latest airflow version (as it can clear things up)

> Airflow was developed as a solution for ETL needs. In the ETL world, you typically summarize data. So, if you want to summarize data for 2016-02-19, you would do it at 2016-02-20 midnight UTC, which would be right after all data for 2016-02-19 becomes available. This interval between midnights of 2016-02-19 and 2016-02-20 is called the data interval

Meaning, on a daily schedule with a start date of `2016-02-19` and lets assume the current date in real life is just the next day `2016-02-20` then there should be only one dag run:

Execution date = `2016-02-19`, data interval `2016-02-19` -> `2016-02-20`.

But if we had a different start date of `2016-02-18` that would result in 2 dag runs:

- Execution date = `2016-02-18`, data interval `2016-02-18` -> `2016-02-19`.
- Execution date = `2016-02-19`, data interval `2016-02-19` -> `2016-02-20`.

So,

> what exactly starts at the start date?

I guess nothing, it's a reference point in time for the scheduling logic. When should it start scheduling dag runs!

> What is executed at execution date?

If it's the first dag run, again, nothing :)

else, you could always assume a dag run related to "previous" execution date.

To try and reduce the confusion you can think about data intervals instead of single execution date as mentioned [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#what-does-execution-date-mean)

> However, you should always use data_interval_start or data_interval_end if possible, since those names are semantically more correct and less prone to misunderstandings.

Hope that helps a bit.